# How do I SSH to EC2 instance with pem key using Python ( without paramiko module)

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

How can I log in to EC2 Instance with pem key using python without using paramiko module, The below code with paramiko works but I need without paramiko.

```
def ssh_login(self):

    try:
        cert = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("key.pem")
        c = paramiko.SSHClient()
        c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        print "connecting..."
        c.connect( hostname = "10.0.0.0", username = "example", pkey = cert )
        print "connected!!!"
        stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('ls')
        print stdout.readlines()
        c.close()

    except:
        print("Connection Failed!!!")
```

Comment: just without paramiko or without any 3rd party module? because the latter is more difficult

Comment: I tried with subprocess also, I am able to login to host but It's not fulfilling the other execution part. As I need to execute one shell script file ( Which takes more time for execution) On that EC2 instance and capture the output.

Comment: https://github.com/trigger/trigger